# Automatically minify all node_modules

Tags: node.js, minify

Is there a tool that you can run where it would take every single javascript file inside the node_modules and replaces it with its minified version?

I realize this is a very simple task that can be accomplished with looping through all .js files and passing them through a minifier, but my implementation would be slow and was hoping somebody might have  a "smarter" way of doing it.

Comment: Can you elloborate what for you would like to minify all the node modules in your project?

Comment: @kentor to reduce the total size of the node_modules folder.

Comment: How big is your node_modules folder that it even becomes an issue? Also, any time you update a package you'd have to re-minify.

Comment: Well I already knew that you wanted to minimise the Node modules folder in order to save space, but why do you want to do that in the first place? You aren’t supposed to commit the node folder anyways?

Comment: @kentor this is for Serverless application. In all Serverless platforms (Google, Amazon, Azure), you zip and include node_modules. So minifying the files will reduce the size of the artifact and increase performance a lot.

Comment: @Kousha did you ever find a way to minify all of your node_modules?

Comment: @MiguelCoder I have not. Well nothing that is speed worthy.

Comment: @Kousha I'm going to try and Uglify it today using webpack. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Has anyone found a good answer to this question? I have a similar use case in which I want to distribute a package with all the dependencies included and that is ready for execution, and I need it to be as small as possible.

Comment: @MiguelCoder any success/update?

Comment: I'll try a POC.

Comment: If this is a serverless application why does it need "node_modules"? Are you running NodeJS or trying to bundle browser code?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem to solve, related to the dimensions of a layer to be deployed over a Lambda AWS Layer framework.
In my case the problem was related to the fact that the output layer started to increase its dimension and there was a problem both on the limitations from AWS and from a performance point of view (try to think at loading a layer of, say, 100MB compared to one of 40MB).

Anyway, given that overview I managed to do a three steps procedure in order to achieve a proper compression for the node_modules folder, and then the overall layer size.

1. Using [modclean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean) to remove unnecessary files and folders from the `node_modules` directory based on predefined and custom glob patterns.
2. Using [node-prune](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-prune) a script to prune unnecessary files from `node_modules` directory, such as markdown, typescript source files and so on.
3. Finally we can run [minify-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify-all) a function to minify all javascript and css files in nested folder as well.

The bash script file to be used in order to achieve a proper compression is the following one (in my case I had a 249MB `node_modules` folder and after the script it became 120MB):

```
npm install -g modclean
npm install -g minify-all
npm install -g node-prune

# The following will install the dependencies into the node_modules folder,
# starting from a package.json file.
npm install

# The following line will remove all the unnecessary files and folders
# with caution to all the dependencies.
modclean -n default:safe,default:caution -r

# The following will prune unnecessary files.
node-prune

# The following with minify all the javascript and css files.
minify-all
```

Please note that the 3rd step requires a lot of time in order to complete.

Comment: `modclean` is an awesome package, you can get almost 20% in size reduction. The other two not so much. Good tips though!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it seems like this should work. You will have to install webpack

First you will have to install webpack

```
$ npm install -g webpack
```

Then you will have to install uglify-js plugin

```
$ npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

--webpack.config.js

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      }),
    ],
  }
};
```

Then in your terminal run

```
$ webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Comment: How fast (rather slow) is this? I'm assuming it would take a long time?

Comment: Very fast. Couple of minutes at the most.